# Is the given data enough to find the answer?

Tags: linear-algebra

I found a question on a textbook of maths on the topic Direct and indirect variations. The question is :

> If 10 men and 14 women can earn Rs 1750 per day. How much would 10 men and 10 women can earn per day?

I spent almost half an hour on this question but unable to find a method to solve this. may be the data given in this question is insufficient to get the answer. OR there is a method to solve this?

Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $10m+14w = 1750 \rightarrow 10m = 1750-14w$, now put it into $10w+10m = x$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Are you sure about the precise formulation? "How much would ... can earn" is not correct English.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : Copied from a textbook as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Less, I bet ! I suppose that some information is missing ... except if men and women earn  the same (what I hope and wish). For this optimistic case, you have the answer very quickly.

Comment: Then the solution is trivial.

Comment: I am afraid it is not. In how many countries are male and female earnings the same for the same qualification and the same job ? In the real word, I am afraid you miss some information (for example, females are paid 25% less than males)

Answer (score 0):

The equation for the data known would be $10m+14w=1750$ and then you would like to find the amount $x$ satisfying $10m+10w=x$. This results in the linear system
$$
\begin{cases}
10m+14w &= 1750\\
10m+10w &= x
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly you are missing an equation (additional info); assuming men and women get equal gains, the last info would be $m=w$ with which the system has unique solution. Then again, it depends on the missing info.

Comment: So I am correct that the provided information is not enough to get the answer.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct ... under the awful assumption that gender impacts the earning !

Answer (score 0):

Since people doing different things earn different wages, there is clearly no sense to the stated hypothesis: any number of people can earn about anything you like if you select them properly.

However, if one is assuming that these people are being paid by the same employer for the same work, and that proper laws for gender equality are in place, then they must all earn the same amount and the problem can easily be solved (distinguishing men from women then is a red herring, just replace them by "persons" throughout).

I sincerely hope this textbook is not doing implicit advocacy of gender inequality.

Comment: Interesting problem, isn't ?